# Is it enough to launch Sonar only once a day or week?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I have been digging quite a bit on Sonar best practices. The consensus seems to be that Sonar would be launched only once a day or week, e.g. during the night. However, what if one uses a CI server such as Jenkins? Jenkins builds on every SVN commit, runs unit tests, deploys to staging environment, runs Selenium tests, etc. The way I understand it, all this additional information is lost if Sonar is launched only once a day/week. Most likely all the team's code problems and failing tests have been resolved on in the afternoon or end of the week. Sonar runs probably on Sunday night or every night. The application is pre-built and tested, and then Sonar analysis is executed based on that information. Most likely all tests pass, no major code problems are left in the repository, and the QA team incorrectly believes that there are no problems since all Sonar reports display green. However, during the day/week it is possible that the project has been a total mess with broken builds etc., but is never displayed in Sonar reports :)

Am I missing something here, or should Sonar actually be executed upon every commit, or at least once an hour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all dependes on your need and your team velocity to develop new code, test and integrate new functionalities into the project.

If you have a sprint with a time box of a web, probably that on the weekend, the version that started on monday is stable, and therefore bug free, or only a few bugs. If your sprint time box is a week, i would higly recommend at least once a day, so you can get defects running unit tests and so on, giving a good reality on your project quality.

I would recommend these practices:

1. Using code coverage like Cobertura, running unit tests at least once a day;
2. Using code analysis like PMD, checkstyle and so on. If possible, create your own rules that applies to your architecture, generating more value for your project in terms of quality.
3. Considering your time box for a Sprint, choose a frequency for your builds in sonar and schedule a cron job that runs it only when you really need it(since its time consuming).

These are practices I use in my projects, but you have to look closely to your needs, since the tool (Sonar) is to help you with information about the quality of your project, and therefore, your architecture, your team and your engineering practices.

Comment: Good points, thanks. My other comment above partly targets your answer too, in terms that one would/should really have only one repository for quality reports. The Jenkins cobertura reports may indicate of huge quality problems, but are never displayed in Sonar. I wonder, one could of course execute Sonar with unit test reports but _without_ code analysis on every commit, and execute _both_ test reports and code analysis reports once a day or even week. One would have to maintain separate Sonar executing configs, but that may be ok...

Comment: Sonar lacks of quality to show information about tests and quality of your code. In fact, Sonar is only a tools that tries to gather informations using third party tools, like Cobertura, PMD, Checkstyle and so on in a web interface. It could get much better than it is.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the data that Sonar collects is static analysis info (complexity, code style violations and so on) that wouldn't change much from build to build unless the code is refactored, so it should be enough to run it once a day.  Consider also that Sonar analysis will add to your build execution time - at my work it can add 2 or 3 minutes to a build that only takes that long to compile and test in the first place.

If you want to collect code coverage and test results for every CI build, you can do that in Jenkins and use Jenkins as an early warning system for build health, leaving Sonar for more long term analysis of overall code quality and maintainability.

You can still trend code coverage and test results in Sonar as you mentioned in your question, you just won't have it for every CI build

Comment: One could execute unit tests with cobertura at every commit and run the Sonar analysis once every night. However, I think that defeats the whole point of using Sonar as your centralized quality repository. If cobertura is executed without Sonar, then you will start having quality metrics in two places: Jenkins and Sonar. Someone from QA will look at your Sonar metrics and say "this is great, but how are you _really_ doing?" Then you have to start digging your _other_ test reports that are not part of sonar, and you discover that you are not doing so well in the project after all in quality...

Comment: That's true, it depends on your definition of quality - in my experience it's very hard to have a single place that you can go to get an overview of all the factors that contribute to your product's quality.  So I use my CI system to alert me of immediate quality "breakages" (failing compilation, test failures, code coverage dropping below a threshold, etc.) and keep Sonar for more long term trending.  You can still trend code coverage and test results in Sonar as you mentioned in your question, you just won't have it for every CI build.

Answer (score 1):

Running Sonar once a day/week should not be considered 'best practice'. It might be the best currently possible, considering available hardware and quality of quality measurements, but as you say, in a CI environment you need feedback every commit (and actually should have it inside the commit too, like you can have with Smalltalk & MOOSE on every method save). Code complexity and test coverage change of the parts I'm currently working on are some of the visualizations/measurements I like having at a much smaller granularity than once a day.

That Sonar adds a lot of time to your build is an implementation problem, not a fundamental, and can be tackled in a number of different ways: caching information, splitting between slow and fast measurements, splitting in modules, running asynchronously, etc.